# How to single out build jobs to be excluded from a specific Node

Tags: jenkins

I have this asymmetry in resources in our build Nodes where one particular node is a weaker machine that is competent for some of our smaller applications but there's some large application I wish not to build on this weak node. Since the number of big jobs is limited I'd rather not dispense labels for each application and just omit those particular big job labels from that particular node, I'm hoping there's an inverse exclusion logic I can exploit so that a singular exclusion is specified rather than an exhaustive big list of inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like labels aren't just literal labels but can be built up into label expressions. Good feature, I can specify `!NodeName` for those specific big build jobs and a whole bunch of other logic too now that I know about this.